# How to solve unhandled exception: ArumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to catch an unhandled exception but it still occurs an error. Where do I need to start my "try" and when/how do I need to catch it ?
Here is my code:

```
            String allMarks = "";
            String toString1 = "";
            String toString2 = "";

            if (eventcounter.Count > 2)
            {
                allMarks = allMarks + eventcounter[0];

                for (int i = 0; i < eventcounter.Count; i++)
                {
                    toString1 = eventcounter[i].ToString();

                    for (int j = 1; j <= eventcounter.Count; j++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            toString2 = eventcounter[j].ToString();
                        }
                        catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("not enough elements to compare");
                            throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index parameter is out of range");
                        }

                        if (toString1 != toString2)//(eventcounter[i] != eventcounter[j])
                        {
                            allMarks = allMarks + eventcounter[j];
                            Console.WriteLine(allMarks);
                            //_sensorTextView3.Text = string.Format("Eventcounter: {0}", allMarks);
                        }
                    }
                }
               // _sensorTextView3.Text += allMarks;
            }
```

UPDATE:
Okay I am using only one loop now instead of two but still the error occurs whenever run the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < eventcounter.Count; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        toString1 = eventcounter[i].ToString();
                        toString2 = eventcounter[i + 1].ToString();
                    }
                    catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
                    {

                        throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index parameter is out of range");
                    }

                    if (toString1 != toString2)
                    {
                        allMarks = allMarks + eventcounter[i+1];
                        Console.WriteLine(allMarks);
                    }
```

Comment: `for (int j = 1; j <= eventcounter.Count; j++)` should probably be `for (int j = 1; j < eventcounter.Count; j++)` and the exception probably occurs in `allMarks = allMarks + eventcounter[j];` (outside of the try/catch block)

Comment: You can put your `try` block before your `if` statement and catch any corresponding exceptions related to your indexes or conversions.

Comment: `IndexOutOfRangeException` should never be caught; it's what Eric Lippert calls a [bone-headed exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/), in that your code shouldn't be causing it in the first place. Arrays are indexed from 0 and have valid indexes from 0 to their length, *exclusive*; change your `<= Count` checks to `< Count`. Better yet, see if you can do this without nested loops -- do you really need to compare every element to every other element, repeatedly, or could this be done in one loop? (Hint: it can.)

Comment: Instead of **handling** an exception you should allways try to **avoid** it in the first place. In particular in a case of a `NullReference-`, `Argument-` or `IndexOutOfRangeException` - to name only a few. Anyway: where *does* your exception occur? Obviously it´s not within the `eventCouinter[j].ToString`-part.

Comment: What is the *initial problem* you are trying to solve, please?

Comment: @JeroenMostert oh yes you are right, I have changed it to just one loop :) thanks

Comment: I did but still get the error. Does it matter where to put the catch argument? I did it in the very end

Comment: I am saving all events form my Sensor data in an eventcounter. But I only want to save and also display when the Value changes so I go through each two eleemnts of my event counter to compare if the value has changed and if yes to save it in allMarks as a String

Answer (score 0):

`eventcounter` contains `eventcounter.Count` elements, numbered from `0` to `eventcounter.Count-1`.

with

```
for (int j = 1; j <= eventcounter.Count; j++)
```

at some point `j` will become equal to `eventcounter.Count`. Since the element number range is [`0`, `eventcounter.Count`], an attempt to access element number `eventcounter.Count` throws `IndexOutOfRangeException`.